# Web Part Connections SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, connected-web-parts

I am trying to connect two webparts together in SP 2013. This guy has a youtube [video](http://youtu.be/cYU8bQ6Sw8I) on this.

However, I can't seem to find the connection link. Are webpart connections available in SharePoint 2013? If so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

```
SUPPORTED LIST TYPES
 - Announcements
 - Contacts
 - Events
 - Issues
 - Links
 - Tasks
 - Custom lists
 - Lists that contain data imported from a spreadsheet
 - Document libraries
 - Form libraries


UNSUPPORTED LIST TYPES
 - Calendar view of an Events list
 - Discussion boards
 - Surveys
 - Picture libraries
 - Site and list template catalogs
 - Web Part galleries
 - Data sources
```

Answer (score 2):

Even on web parts that support connections, the "Connections" option only shows up after you choose "Edit web part"

Comment: I see the 'Connections' option and can connect to the other web part (doc library). Once I select the connection, the 'select' column appears. Initially, when I saved the changes, the select column disappeared, so I was unable to use the filter. However, after a few tries (and a bit of patience), eventually the full dialog appeared, allowing me to select the corresponding columns to connect, and the filter worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

The connections menu is only available if both web parts support a compatible connection type.

You don't specify which web parts you're using so I assume that they don't both support connections.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to give a tips about the function "Related list". There is no need to make any specific *share to* of *receive from*.
Select the web part. Go to the web part menue. Click on "Insert related list". If you have made any links between them earlier in one or more fields, you will see the related lists to pick from.

[image]

Good luck!